# Domain redirecting to a different domain with a slightly modified path

Tags: .htaccess, dns

So I want to redirect

domain2.com/path/url to a different domain, domain1.com/pathDurl where the / is replaced by a D or other character?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following redirect in /domain2/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/path/(.+)$ http://domain1.com/pathD$1
```

This will redirect :

- http://domain2.com/path/foobar

to

- http://domain1.com/pathDfoobar